# gdb - execute current line without moving on

Tags: gdb, cgdb

This has probably been asked elsewhere, but was a bit of a tricky one to google.

I am debugging some code like the following in gdb (or cgdb more specifically):

```
if(something) {
  string a = stringMaker();
  string b = stringMaker();
}
```

As I step through using 'n', the cursor will reach the 'string b' line. At this point I can inspect the value of a, but b won't have been populated yet as that line hasn't been executed. Another press of 'n' will execute that line, but will then also move outside the if loop and b will now be out of scope. Is there a way to execute the current line without moving on so that its result can be inspected before it goes out of scope?

Comment: I don't think this can be done with gcc or other compilers that only emit source-to-compiled-code mappings at the granularity of a line. As a workaround, you can set a breakpoint at the `string b =` line with an attached command that does `watch b`, then continues. gdb ought to stop just after `b` is written to, although this might be in the middle of a constructor or other string class code rather than in your code.

Comment: `watch` looks like a reasonable answer, that seems about as close as I can get to what I wanted. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Another press of 'n' will execute that line, but will then also move
> outside the if loop and b will now be out of scope

The problem is that `next` executes too much instructions and `b` variable becomes unavailable. You can substitute this single `next` with a number of `step` and `finish` commands to achieve more granularity in debugging and stop immediately after `b` was constructed. Here is sample gdb session for test program:

```
[ks@localhost ~]$ cat ttt.cpp 
#include <string>

int main()
{
  if (true)
  {
    std::string a = "aaa";
    std::string b = "bbb";
  }
  return 0;
}
[ks@localhost ~]$ gdb -q a.out 
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) start 
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40081f: file ttt.cpp, line 7.
Starting program: /home/ks/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at ttt.cpp:7
7       std::string a = "aaa";
(gdb) n
8       std::string b = "bbb";
(gdb) p b
$1 = ""
(gdb) s
std::allocator<char>::allocator (this=0x7fffffffde8f) at /usr/src/debug/gcc-5.1.1-20150618/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/allocator.h:113
113       allocator() throw() { }
(gdb) fin
Run till exit from #0  std::allocator<char>::allocator (this=0x7fffffffde8f) at /usr/src/debug/gcc-5.1.1-20150618/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/allocator.h:113
0x0000000000400858 in main () at ttt.cpp:8
8       std::string b = "bbb";
(gdb) s
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string (this=0x7fffffffde70, __s=0x400984 "bbb", __a=...) at /usr/src/debug/gcc-5.1.1-20150618/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:656
656     basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::
(gdb) fin
Run till exit from #0  std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string (this=0x7fffffffde70, __s=0x400984 "bbb", __a=...) at /usr/src/debug/gcc-5.1.1-20150618/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:656
0x000000000040086d in main () at ttt.cpp:8
8       std::string b = "bbb";
(gdb) p b
$2 = "bbb"
```

Comment: This works for me. I can run `s` followed by `fin` on any command that has underlying implementation. Of course doing it in a single command would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the code `b;` the line afterwards. i.e.

```
if(something) {
  string a = stringMaker();
  string b = stringMaker();
  b; // Break point here
}
```

Comment: This kind of works - it's obviously not ideal though. I say kind of since the file I'm debugging might not be one I'm editing but from somewhere else in the codebase, so it's not trivial to make a change in it and rebuild with my own version

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always to a

```
(gdb) p stringMaker();
```

regardless of the line you're in given that `stringMaker()` is accessible. You can execute any kind statements , even involving variables if those variables are in current scope. For more advanced usage, you can use `gdb`'s internal variables(`$1,$2` etc) to store certain result to use it later when the variables involved in that previous computation went out of scope.

Finally God(whatever that may be) send us `gdb Python API`. just type `py` and demolish your code to such extent that you will forget what you were doing at the first place.